Toggle anchor on OSB board
Please, anyone ever tested toggle anchor on OSB board, does it hold more than drywall? I believe so, any experience will be appreciated, TIA.
Anchor: https://a.co/d/2pBDbHI

Will depend on the thickness of the OSB and the weight of the object.  Usually OSB is much more solid/less pull out than weak drywall.  Punching drywall you might say ow when your fist goes though.  Punching OSB is a broken hand and maybe a dent in the OSB.

Heavy and/or expensive objects are best anchored to wood studs.  Second best is to run 2x4s/plywood across studs and screw in.  Toggle bolts in OSB is third best.  We do not talk about drywall.
